# How can I get the current WBNB balance once every 3 seconds in python/web3.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abi, web3py

I need help. I want to rotate the FIT token liquidity balance every 3 seconds but I need some help

```
bsc = "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))
#WBNB
abi = json.loads('[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs": 
[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}, 
{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"guy","type":"address"}, 
{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs": 
[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}, 
{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs": 
[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}, 
{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"src","type":"address"},{"name":"dst","type":"address"}, 
{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs": 
[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}, 
{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdraw","outputs": 
[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}, 
{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs": 
[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}, 
{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs": 
[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}, 
{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":        
[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}, 
{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dst","type":"address"}, 
{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs": 
[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}, 
{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"deposit","outputs": 
[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs": 
[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs": 
[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}, 
{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs": 
[{"indexed":true,"name":"src","type":"address"}, 
{"indexed":true,"name":"guy","type":"address"}, 
{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"}, 
{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"src","type":"address"}, 
{"indexed":true,"name":"dst","type":"address"}, 
{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}, 
{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"dst","type":"address"}, 
{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Deposit","type":"event"}, 
{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"src","type":"address"}, 
{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Withdrawal","type":"event"}]')

address = '0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c'

contract = web3.eth.contract(address=address , abi=abi)

print(contract.functions.name().call())

balance = contract.functions.balanceOf('0x5e8ce185475855E60fA121389331cd6cEd61ea57').call()

print(web3.fromWei(balance, 'ether'))
```

I'm getting updated information.
But I want to get new updated information every 3 seconds.
I try this ;

```
Ba = balance
while Ba > 0:
    if Ba > 0:
       print(web3.fromWei(balance, 'ether'))
       time.sleep(3)
    
    else:
        print('0')
```

But this prints me a single result multiple times :(

Answer (score 0):

you need to use .call() every time to refresh the balance!

```
balance = contract.functions.balanceOf('0x5e8ce185475855E60fA121389331cd6cEd61ea57')

while True:
     print(web3.fromWei(balance.call(), 'ether'))
     time.sleep(3)
```